# Seasonality adjustment

Tags: time-series, seasonality

[image]I have a monthly serie of the importation of apples. As I constructed the Buys-Ballot table, I found out that the serie is seasonal, in March for four years and in April for the later three years. What to do to deseasonal it since the seasonal month has changed??

[image]

Comment: Could you include a plot of your data, preferably arranged by seasons? It can be done, for example, using the function `seasonplot` from the "forecast" package in R. Extra to that, you could also include some numerical measures of seasonality if you have obtained any so far.

Comment: I've added the plot. I'm using eviews, not R

Comment: Then could you plot the twelve months of 2009, then the twelve months of 2010 on top in the same graph, then 2011 on top and so on (probably using different colours)? From the current graph it appears that not only March/April but also other months are somehow special, i.e. the seasonal pattern does not only have one spike per year and a flat line for the rest of the year. If you want to seasonally adjust the data, you could just use monthly dummies, for example. Of course, if *the seasonal month has changed*, probably you need a more advanced approach.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like simple dummies could work alright. The fact that the peak month has changed recently is somewhat worrying, but the change does not seem to be very large. You could, for example, weight the different years differently (assign larger weights for more recent years). It should work fine.

Comment: Sorry I've studied seasonal adjustment in french, my english is not good. Can you briefly explain what is "Simple dummies", "weight" ??

Comment: By *simple dummies* I mean *dummy variables* or *indicator variables* that have value 1 for the particular month and zero elsewhere. E.g. a January dummy looks like (1,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, ...), a February dummy looks like (0,1,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, ...), and so on. Weights can be used for weighting observations when fitting a regression model. Check *weighted least squares* or *WLS*.

Comment: Ok. A last question please: In your opinion, what could be the best technique to forecast(predict) the future values ?

Comment: Extrapolate the fitted seasonal pattern. Once you have estimated the coefficients on the dummy variables, it is straightforward, because you have no problem predicting *when* January of February will occur next year. So just take the fitted pattern (which must repeat itself from year to year by contruction) and extrapolate it into the future.

Comment: If you are going to come back, I could edit your post to include the extra questions and post my answer (a coherent collection of my comments). That way we could "close" the thread.

Comment: Ok I have no objection, Please do you have a document which explain your answers or an example to share ?

Comment: The suggestion I gave you is pretty basic. It consists of (1) estimating seasonality and (2) extrapolating it with the goal of forecasting. Each of these steps is discussed in basic forecasting and/or econometrics textbooks. The combination of the two is quite natural and still very basic, but I am not sure I have a reference for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can seasonal adjust the data with X-13ARIMA-SEATS. X-13ARIMA-SEATS is a pretty powerful tool and deals with changing seasonal patterns. You can get the X-13ARIMA-SEATS fortan libraries from the US Census Bureau [here](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/), but most statistical software include a wrapper around the X-13ARIMA-SEATS program. It should be fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect the month has changed, and you know the change is in year 4, then you can add the month dummies Richard suggested. You will do a better job by adding interaction terms also, i.e. regress the seasonal variable on month dummies (denoted i.month) and interaction terms (A x i.month) and (B x i.month) where A = 1 if year <= 4, 0 otherwise, and B = 1 if year > 4, 0 otherwise. That way you will capture the shift in the seasonality.